# Login failed for user. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL server connection - SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005

I'm running the following scripts to

1. Create a database
2. Create Login
3. Assign Login to the database
4. Assign database roles
5. Create tables in the database

The scripts are -

```
if not exists (
select *
from master.dbo.sysdatabases
where name = 'TESTDB')
create database TESTDB
GO

if not exists(select * from master.dbo.syslogins where name = 'testuser')
EXEC [TESTDB].dbo.sp_addlogin @loginame = N'testuser', @passwd = 'test@2010', @defdb = N'TESTDB', @deflanguage = N'us_english'
GO

USE [TESTDB]
GO
/****** Object:  User [MPS]    Script Date: 01/22/2011 17:53:17 ******/
GO              
if exists(select * from master.dbo.syslogins where name = 'testuser' AND dbname = 'TESTDB')
EXEC dbo.sp_grantdbaccess @loginame = N'testuser'
GO

USE [TESTDB]

EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'testuser'
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_accessadmin', 'testuser'
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_securityadmin', 'testuser'

USE [TESTDB]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[tblJobs]    Script Date: 01/22/2011 17:04:05 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('tblJobs','U') is null
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblJobs](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [JobTitle] [nvarchar](4000) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
END
```

Everything is getting created without any issue. But when I try to login using testuser I get the error -

**Login failed for user 'testuser'. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL server connection.**

Any ideas why?

Comment: What are you using to login when you get the error? SSMS? Or an application connecting with a connection string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be that your server is not configured to use mixed mode authentication.

Go to server-properties and select SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode.

[image]